# If I have built for iOS 4.3 my App, will it run on a device with OS 4.2?

Tags: ios, build-process

Will backward compatibility supported for iOS?
If I have built for iOS 4.3 my App, will it run on a device with OS 4.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "built for". Backward compatibility is not defined by the release number of the SDK you are building against. For example, with the SDK 4.3, you can build applications that will run on iOS 4.2 (and earlier of course).

*You* define the minimum version of iOS your application will support, by filling in the Deployment Target entry of the target info page. If you put "4.3" in there, then your application will not even install on a machine running iOS 4.2 or earlier.

It also remains then your responsibility not to use APIs that are not available on the versions of iOS you want to support.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to set the "iOS Deployment Target" to "iOS 4.1".